# Im trying to hide an element when the page opens and then show when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

Im trying to hide an element when the page opens and then show when a button is clicked but it doesnt show the element. i want the form with id extraForm to be hidden until button is pressed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script src="Javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#extraForm").hide()
});
$('#showForm').click(function(){
$('#extraForm').show();
});
</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='website.css'>
</head>
<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<table> <table border="1"> <tr>
<tr> <td> First Name:     </td> <td> <input type="text" name="firstName">  </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> Last Name:      </td> <td> <input type="text" name="lastName">   </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Dorm Name:      </td> <td> <input type="text" name="dormName">   </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> Room Number:    </td> <td> <input type="text" name="roomNumber"> </td> </tr>

<tr> <td> Pizza Type:     </td> <td> <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Cheese">       
Cheese
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni <br>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Buffalo Chicken"> Buffalo Chicken </td>
<tr> <td> Number of Pizza's:  <td>   <input type="text" name="pizzaNumber"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td> <td>  <input type="submit"> </tr> </td>

<table> <table border="1" id="extraForm">
<tr> <td> <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Cheese"> Cheese</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Buffalo Chicken"> Buffalo Chicken      
</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="Pepperoni"> Pepperoni</td> </tr>
<input type="button" name="showForm" value="Add Pizza" id="showForm">
</table>


</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmmm... you're missing an opening `<html>` tag...

Answer (score 6):

It is always better to use CSS to hide elements that you don't need on page load

```css
#extraForm { display: none }​
```

Your script doesn't work because you try to attach the event listener to an element that doesn't yet exist when the script runs. To fix it your jQuery needs to wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('#showForm').click(function() {
        $('#extraForm').show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjmqB/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you need the form to be hidden when the page loads you could use CSS to hide it.

```
<table border="1" id="extraForm" style="display:none">
```

When you need the form to be displayed, simply use
`$('#extraForm').show();`

[Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AAKVk/1/)

Dont forget to include the jquery library in your code.

Answer (score 1):

put the script et the end of your HTML document or wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // place code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#extraForm").hide()
        $('#showForm').click(function(){
            $('#extraForm').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

`$("#extraForm").hide()` doesn't need to be in a function - it runs when the page loads.